# Should I implement IDisposable on a singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, singleton, idisposable

I have a windows service, which contains a singleton which in turn uses some loggers, message queue listeners and so on. Those classes implements `IDisposable`. Should I implement `IDisposable` in singleton itself or do something else to ensure that after service stop/crashing everything will be okay with native resources?
The singleton is implemented like this:

```
public class Temp
{
   private static readonly Lazy<Temp> instance = new Lazy<Temp>(() => new Temp());

   private Temp()
   {
      // create IDisposable objects which use native resources
   }

   public static Temp Instance
   {
      get
      {
         return instance.Value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The use of Lazy is entirely pointless here.

Comment: @weston http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: Chances are, you should not implement a singleton at all. Why would you need one in a windows service?

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather *not implement* `IDisposable` on singleton: `IDisposable` *provokes* developer to *Dispose* the (single) instance:

```
  using(var temp = Temp.Instance) {
    ...
  }
```

which leads to (possible) *crash* in *some other part of the application* (since the single `Temp` instance has been disposed):

```
  Temp.Instance.SomeFucntion(); // <- possible fail, since Temp.Instanceis disposed
```

In some rare case if you *have to release* some resouces aquired, I'd use `ProcessExit`
event

```
public class Temp {
   private static readonly Lazy<Temp> instance = new Lazy<Temp>(() => new Temp());

   private void OnProcessExit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // Release native resource if required:
     // some resources e.g. files will be closed automatically,
     // but some e.g. transactions should be closed (commit/rollback) manually
     try {  
       ...
     }
     finally { 
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit -= OnProcessExit;
     }   
   }

   private Temp() {
     // create IDisposable objects which use native resources

     // If you have to release some resouces on exit
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += OnProcessExit;
   }

   public static Temp Instance {
     get {
       return instance.Value;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit -= OnProcessExit; inside finally.

Comment: @Qué Padre: Thank you! You're quite right: it should be AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit -= OnProcessExit

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx. I tried to exit a console application with Ctrl+C and looks like the event is not fired in this case as well.

Comment: Yes, when you exit an application abnormaly (explicit process termination, Ctrl+C on console application etc.), neither ProcessExit is fired, nor finally is executed - if you want to terminate the application should terminate without any additional actions (imagine that application hangs on ProcessExit).

Answer (score 2):

No; Singleton shouldn't implement `IDisposable`. What if someone disposes the instance prematurely when others are in need of that?

Also note that implementing `IDisposable` will not help you when your service is crashed/stopped. You'll have to dispose it manually! but you can't find right time to do it.

Comment: so, what can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

If a type will be returned from a factory that will sometimes need to be cleaned up when the caller is done with them, the type should implement `IDisposable`.  If a particular factory returns a shared singleton object that doesn't actually need any resources, the object returned by the factory should have a `Dispose` method which silently does nothing.  If the factory needs to provide access to a shared singleton resources (e.g. an immutable bitmap stored in a GDI object), it should return a wrapper which will notify the factory when it its `Dispose` method is called; the factory can then maintain a reference count of wrapper objects and clean up the resource once it knows that no more wrappers will be created and all existing wrappers have been disposed.