# Should I create and reuse AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient as a singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

The [SES Docs for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-net.html) show sending email using `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` initialized with a `using` statement:

```
using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
{
    //...
}
```

I get that this is ok for an example, however, in my production application, should I initialize `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` just once and reuse it thereafter?

```
// MailSender is registered with DI as Singleton
public class MailSender
{
    private AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient _client;

    public MailSender()
    {
        _client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
    }

    public void SendEmail()
    {
        // ...
        _client.SendEmail(request);
    }
}
```

My production application is sending a high volume of emails. I am not sure how the `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` object behaves, but it would seem more performant to create a single instance rather than newing it up every time an email is sent out.

Comment: It's an IDisposable.  `IDisposable` *provokes* the developer to dispose of the instance.  Disposing a singleton could cause crashes in parts of your application.  Why do you need it to be a singleton?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I implement IDisposable on a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140593/should-i-implement-idisposable-on-a-singleton)

Comment: My production application is sending a high volume of emails. I am not sure how the `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` object behaves, but it would seem more performant to create a single instance rather than newing it up every time an email is sent out.

Comment: I'd advise against the Singleton though.  There's always ways to re-architect your logic in such away that you're sending out emails in batches.  For example:  `using(var emailer) { foreach(var email) { emailer.Send(email) } }`

Answer (score 5):

When reusing a class, your concern is not only performance but also concurrency.

That being said, a quick look at the [source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/89547149/) reveals this class calls its base class `AmazonWebServiceClient`'s `Dispose` method:

```
#region Dispose

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
#endregion
```

The base class does not override the Dispose method and instead relies on its own base class `AbstractWebServiceClient`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements the Dispose pattern for the AmazonWebServiceClient
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">Whether this object is being disposed via a call to Dispose
/// or garbage collected.</param>
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.disposed)
    {
        if (disposing && logger != null)
        {
            logger.Flush();
            logger = null;
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Notice the `Dispose` method is cleaning up an internal instance of a logger.

So, in terms of performance, there is certainly something to be gained. However, as far as concurrency is concerned, there is no mention of the class being thread-safe in the code comments.

Their [client documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/object-lifecycles/) on life cycles however does mention thread safety and class reuse:

> The best-known aspect of the AWS SDK for .NET are the various service
>   clients that you can use to interact with AWS. Client objects are
>   **thread safe**, disposable, and **can be reused**. (Client objects are
>   inexpensive, so **you are not incurring a large overhead** by constructing
>   multiple instances, but **it’s not a bad idea to create and reuse** a
>   client.)

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always instantiate classes that you're going to use more than once. In a non-GarbageCollector language (like C++) it could be a problem to instantiate classes everywhere and not disposing them.