# How to Close a Singleton service that does not implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection, idisposable

I have a singleton service that talks to a Service Bus. My problem is that I cannot implement `IDisposable` elegantly since the "Close" calls to the service bus clients are `async` - `CloseAsync()`.

Thus, my service class also implements a `CloseAsync` method which defers to the service bus client's `CloseAsync`. 
From what I can gather my options are:

1. Implement dispose and block while calling `CloseAsync` on the client. Feels wrong.
2. Initialise a member variable in `startup.cs`, add that as a `Singleton`, use `ApplicationLifetime` to register a `ShutDown` handler, and close my clients in there. Seems like overkill. (I've tried this but the code in my `ShutDown` handler is either not hit, or is not being run)
3. Simply leave it, since the application is closing anyway. Tempting, but also feels wrong (I like to clean up).

Is there a way to intercept the disposal of services in the DI container (I'm using the standard `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection`)?

Is it OK to block on an async call within the Dispose method? That way I can make my class self disposing.

Is there another way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: If you have a single instance of this object through the lifetime of your application, why do you care about disposing it? When an application closes, its memory space gets reclaimed by the OS, effectively disposing the entire set of application and any resources it may have created.

Comment: IDisposable makes sense for types of objects that consume a considerable amount of memory and may be created numerous times (typically in quick succession) during the lifetime of your application; for example, bitmap objects that allocate a large buffer for image data, etc.

Comment: Related to @ArashMotamedi's point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140593/should-i-implement-idisposable-on-a-singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single instance of this object through the lifetime of your application, why do you care about disposing it? When an application closes, its memory space gets reclaimed by the OS, effectively disposing the entire set of application and any resources it may have created.

`IDisposable` (explicit disposal) makes sense for types of objects that consume a considerable amount of memory and may be created numerous times (typically in quick succession) during the lifetime of your application; for example, `bitmap` objects that allocate a large buffer for image data, `stream`s, and other data carrying/manipulating objects that you'd instantiate many times. The sort of things that you'd put in a `using` block.

Here's a rule of thumb:

You need `IDisposable` only if: each instance of the object consumes significant amount of memory (think tens of megabytes), you need to create and retain many instances at once, or you need to create many instances in very quick succession. In these cases, you'll benefit from manually disposing the object. If these don't fit your use case, then the garbage collector will do a more than sufficient job cleaning up unused resources.

> [Should I implement IDisposable on a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140593/should-i-implement-idisposable-on-a-singleton)

Thanks @Broots for the useful link.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, and is certainly the answer I was looking for as it keeps the code the cleanest. Thanks for the extra info too, it helps me know when to worry about disposal.

Comment: I suppose one concern I would have in this instance is if messages were about to be sent to the service bus, and the application closed prior to them sending. Being able to await CloseAsync would presumably allow those messages to be sent.

Comment: @brenwebber You can certainly listen for an event (application shutdown, etc.) and call CloseAsync. But this is different than disposing your object. If you go down this path, make sure you put in place enough synchronization and protections in your code such that other parts of your app don't try to submit new messages to the queue once the application shutdown event has been received. You'll need to harmonize different parts of your app a bit.

Comment: @brenwebber If at all possible, try to stay clear of doing this though. You'll find yourself tangled between threads and async operations. Essentially, ask yourself: what's the cost of losing a message? You will inevitably lose messages one way or another (application crash, system crash). So, think about your tolerance level for a message getting lost and design accordingly. Keep it as simple as possible, and only as complicated as absolutely necessary.