# What should the lifetime of RestSharp client wrapper be?

Tags: c#, .net-core, restsharp

During the process of migrating our application to the new [RestSharp version](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107), we notice that the documentation recommends the following usage:

```cs
public class GitHubClient {
    readonly RestClient _client;

    public GitHubClient() {
        _client = new RestClient("https://api.github.com/")
            .AddDefaultHeader(KnownHeaders.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    }

    public Task<GitHubRepo[]> GetRepos()
        => _client.GetAsync<GitHubRepo[]>("users/aspnet/repos");
}
```

Considering that `new RestClient()` under the hood does `new HttpClient(handler)`, should `GitHubClient` be a Singleton? Or its lifetime shouldn't have any impact at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, an API client would be registered as a singleton as it must be thread-safe. In that case, the wrapped instance of `RestClient`, as well as its internal `HttpMessageHandler` (`HttpClient` is not that important here), will be a singleton.

Basically, a plethora of issues of RestSharp was related to its use of the legacy `HttpWebRequest`, which had a primitive `HttpClient` caching inside. `RestRequest`, and, consequently, `HttpWebRequest`, used to have a number of properties that triggered instantiation of a new `HttpMessageHandler` when those properties were changed. And that caused all the issues you can possibly imagine, which are retailed in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#issues-with-the-original-httpclient-class-available-in-net).

Your question reminded me that `HttpClient` is disposable, but the current `RestClient` is not (as per v107.0.4), so I will add it in the next patch.

Comment: I'm not sure if the majority of the developers register their API clients as singleton. If you look [.AddTypedClient<T>](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L320) from Microsoft, they register the client as transient. So, if that's a requirement for RestSharp to work properly/correctly, it would be great to see it added to the documentation.

Might not be the scope of the library, but it would be cool to see DI support using IHttpClientFactory. Thanks for your reply, nevertheless.

Comment: Well, the complexity of transient registration for typed clients and named clients using HttpClientFactory is directly related to that, I agree. I believe it's safe to register RestClient as a singleton. I am looking at HttpClientBuilder and the factory now, hopefully I can provide own extensions for RestSharp later on, but there's some work involved in that.

Comment: I'm confused! Isn't making the API Client Disposable at odds with it being a Singleton? According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22140671/470014 you shouldn't implement IDisposable on a Singleton. Should I get my API Client as a singleton from DI (SimpleInjector) or wrap it in a using (new...) ? The RestSharp usage page says the API Client should be a Singleton and Disposable tho.

Comment: HttpClient is also disposable, and you can use it as a singleton. RestClient is disposable as it holds references to disposable resources, like HttpClient and the message handler.